# lateinit property androidInjector has not been initialized Dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I have the application like this

```
class App : Application() , HasAndroidInjector {

    lateinit var application: Application

    @Inject
    lateinit var androidInjector : DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        this.application = this
    }
}
```

Then I have the `AppComponent`

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        LoginModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: App): AppComponent
    }
}
```

LoginModule is this

```
@Module
abstract class LoginModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [LoginDependencies::class])
    abstract fun bindLoginFragment(): LoginFragment
}
```

And in the `onViewCreated` of the `Fragment` I'm using

```
AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
```

I also have tried to add it on the `onAttach()` but it does not work. It started to crash once I added the

```
@Inject
lateinit var loginPresenter: LoginContract.Presenter
```

If I remove it, it says the same as the question, if I leave the presenter it says that preseter is not being initialized.

Is something I'm missing?

### Edit

Where I'm getting this error

> ```
> Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property androidInjector has not been initialized
> ```

`override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector`

Then I'm getting this also

> at com.testing.login.login.presentation.LoginFragment.onRequestInjection(LoginFragment.kt:31)

`AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)`

This `onRequestInjection` is in a `AbstractFragment` in the `onViewCreated` also I've tried to put it on `onAttach()` but nothing changed.

And my `build.gradle` contains :

this in the :app

```
    api(LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER)
    api(LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER_ANDROID)
    api(LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER_ANDROID_SUPPORT)
    kapt LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER_ANDROID_KAPT
    kapt LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER_KAPT
    kapt LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR
```

and on :login

```
api(LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER)
    api(LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER_ANDROID)
    api(LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER_ANDROID_SUPPORT)
    kapt LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER_ANDROID_KAPT
    kapt LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER_KAPT
    kapt LibrariesDependencies.DAGGER_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR
```

Comment: There could be many reasons why this is happening. On what line are you getting the "presenter not initialized"? What part of the Fragment lifecycle is it happening? Are you running annotation processing on these modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the property that hasn't been initialized happening in the `App` class?
If so, this likely means that you're missing the following in the `onCreate` method of the `App` class.

```
DaggerAppComponent
            .factory()
            .create(this)
            .inject(this)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your application class you define an `@Inject` property, but you don't initialize it anywhere. What you need to do is: first declare `App` as the *entry point* for Dagger-Android purposes:

```kotlin
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: App): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: App) // Let Dagger know your Application class with root dispatching injector
}
```

and then actually create the `AppComponent` instance and use it to bootstrap Dagger and inject `DispatchingAndroidInjector` instance:

```
override fun onCreate() {
  super.onCreate()
  this.application = this

  DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(this).inject(this)
}
```